# Accessing http query string in a xaml file

Tags: xaml

If an HTTP request is made to an asp web page, then the asp code can access the query string via the `Request.QueryString` object.

What's the analagous way to do this in XAML?  For example, say that I wanted to write a simple XAML page that just echoes the query string back in the response.  What would the code for this look like?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention query strings and responses, I'm assuming you're talking about XBAPs (ie WPF applications hosted in the browser).

Check out this blog post:

[How can I pass Querystring parameters to my WPF XBAP Application?](https://learnwpf.com/post/2007/02/24/How-can-I-pass-Querystring-parameters-to-my-WPF-XBAP-Application.aspx)

Once you've got the `ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri` value as a string it should be fairly trivial to pump it into a TextBlock on a page. Heck, you may be able to bind directly to it if you wanted to go that far.